Mid 60's linear regulator power supply - understanding required
I am looking into this 60's Uher Z124 power supply for a portable open reel recorder.
This is a positive ground design (Pin 2), which outputs an unregulated ~12V (Pin 5) and a regulated ~7V (Pin 3).
What in the world are the output (input?) pins 1 and 4 for?
According to the tiny K713 & K714 cable schematics, these might not even connect to the recorder, but it is hard to say with that resolution.
Edit It appears as though the Nicad charging cable shorts pin4 to 5 (+)
Edit: It would also be interesting if someone could "section" this schematic into functional blocks; it looks somewhat esoteric to me.


Images come from Uher Service Manual
A translated quote from the brochure claims that it can charge two different types of batteries when connected with a K713 or 714 cable.. Which cable to use depends on the battery technology.
I highly suspect the two mystery pins somehow regulate charging voltage/current:

The Z124A power supply and charger is used to supply power to the Report 4xxx series tape recorders. It is the successor to the Z124. Its shape allows it to be connected internally (in the battery compartment) and externally (with cable K713 or K714). With an external connection, the Z212 battery (lead K713) or the Z214 battery (NC K714) can be charged using the built-in charging circuit.

The Z212 appears to be lead acid and the Z214 Nicad.

Not so wild guess:
1&4 are the charger terminals of the power supply, lead-acid in that period.
The lamp would light while there was a significant current.

I think so, too. For Nicad, it seems that Pin4 is shorted to gnd (unregulated +) for some reason. I suspect that somehow regulated the voltage on pin 3 down from ~7V to maybe around 6ish?

To support different features across a product line, it is common for an electronic assembly or wire harness to have parts or connections not used in every model.  It is cheaper to build one wire harness with an extra wire or two and use it in many models rather than growing a specific harness for each model.  This affects purchasing, production scheduling, long-term inventory for support and maintenance, etc.

In this case I think this was made specifically for the 4000 series of recorders; the only difference in them how many tracks they had and whether they were stereo or mono. I have added a excerpt that makes me believe these pins are related to the optional battery charging
